# Change custom cell's background without IB

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, cell

I'm overloading my brains on this one.

I've created a table, which contains custom cells (one of a kind). A few days back, I changed the background to the grey you can see in the picture below here.

Now I don't know how I did that....
[image]

I don't think I did this programatically... What else would explain the color in IB?
I also searched my sourcecode, and the line for coloring the cell through code is commented out.

I need to reproduce this coloring on other custom cells. How the heck did I do this? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I thought of the answer while getting a cup of coffee:

Change the tableView's background (so, an other .xib-file) to the grey color to get that effect...